# Cancel the edit action without updating the params

Tags: ember.js

Currently I'm doing an edit function which will pop out a dialog that allow user to edit their details. After editing the details, user can choose to cancel or save the edit action. But now, when the user click cancel, it will update also, I think is because of the `mut` helper. I've hardcoded the value of `name` in `route.js` so that I called it using `model.name`

Here is my code for the template.hbs,

```
Name:
    {{paper-input 
                placeholder="Enter name" 
                value=model.name
                required = true
                onChange=(action (mut model.name))
                errorMessages=(hash required="Name is required.")}}
```

I've tried 2 way that I found:

1.I've tried to install `ember-data-change-tracker`, but it returns error as below.

```
Command failed: yarn add --dev ember-data-change-tracker --non-interactive
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
error ember-data-change-tracker@0.10.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 10". Got "8.12.0"
error Found incompatible module.

yarn add v1.21.1
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.1.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.16.0 || ^10.6.0 || >=11.0.0". Got "8.12.0"
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

2.I've tried to use `rollbackAttributes()` in controller.js, but it doesn't work.

```
closeEditDialog (ev) {
      if(ev == 'cancel') {
        this.set('showEditDialog',false);
        let name = this.get('model.name')
        if (name.hasDirtyAttributes) {
          name.rollbackAttributes();
        }
      }
```

I found another solution, but I don't know how to implement it.

1. Make a copy of model each time before opening a modal
2. When user make changes, work with the copy
3. If the user click "save" action, update the original model

Comment: what is *not working* with `rollbackAttributes()`? It is, indeed, the right solution. Have you checked if you actually *run* `rollbackAttributes()`? Besides that I can really recommend to join the [ember community Discord channel](https://emberjs.com/community/) with many nice people and a more interactive way to help you and understand your problems.

Comment: It return error- `name.rollbackAttributes` is not a function. Btw, thanks for your recommendation, i will join it later.

Comment: That indeed helped me to see your typo.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you call `rollbackAttributes()` on the property, but you have to call it on the model:

```
let model = this.get('model');
if (model.hasDirtyAttributes) {
  model.rollbackAttributes();
}
```

Two notes here:

1. the check `hasDirtyAttributes` is not really necessary. `rollbackAttributes()` will not do anything if `model.hasDirtyAttributes === false`.
2. It will always roll back all *attributes*, but not *relationships*.

Comment: I didn't generate a model for this, this.model return the model from route.js. Is it the reason that cause the rollbackAttributes not working?

Comment: what do you return from `model` your `route.js`? `hasDirtyAttributes`  is indeed a `ember-data` feature. You have to call it on the instance of a model.